Approximating solution to vector recurrence relation with element-wise exponential
$$
\mbox{Let}\ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\ \mbox{and}\ \gamma_{1}, \ldots, \gamma_{n} \in \mathbb{R}\ \mbox{with}\ \gamma_{i} > 0,\ \forall\ i.
$$
$$
\mbox{Define}\ \operatorname{f}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}\ \mbox{by}\ \operatorname{f}\left(\vec{x}\right)
\left[i\right]
=
\exp\left(-\gamma_{i}\vec{x}\left[i\right]\right)
$$
where $\vec{x}\left[i\right]$ denotes the $i$-th coordinate of $\vec{x}$.

Now let $\vec{x}_{0} = 0$ and define $\vec{x}_{1}, \vec{x}_{2}, \ldots \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by the following recurrence:
$$
\vec{x}_{t + 1} = \vec{x}_{t} + {\bf A}\operatorname{f}\left(\vec{x}_{t}\right)
$$
What I want is an approximation of $\vec{x}_{t}$ that is tight up to constant multiplicative factors, i.e. for sufficiently large $t$, each coordinate of the approximation differs from $\vec{x}_{t}\left[i\right]$ by at most a constant multiplicative factor.
In the case $n = 1$, we get a recurrence relation over scalars that can be approximated by a separable ODE. Specifically, the recurrence becomes
$$
x_{t + 1} - x_{t} =
a\exp\left(-\gamma x_{t}\right),
$$
which can be approximated with the ODE
$$
\frac{{\rm d}\operatorname{x}\left(t\right)}
{{\rm d}t} =
a\exp\left(-\gamma x\left(t\right)\right),
$$
and we can solve it by separation to get
$$
\operatorname{x}\left(t\right) = 
{\log\left(1 + a\gamma t\right) \over \gamma},
$$
which seems to be a good approximation for the discrete $\mbox{sequence}\ x_{t}$.
If I try something similar for the case of general $n$, I get the system of ODEs:
$$
\frac{%
{\rm d}\vec{\operatorname{x}}\left(t\right)}
{dt} = {\bf A} \operatorname{f}\left(\vec{\operatorname{x}}
\left(t\right)\right),
$$
and I don't know how to solve this.
Is there an easy extension of my approximation for $n = 1$ to the case of general $n$ ?. If not, how else can I approximate a solution to this vector recurrence relation ?.

If it's important, the matrix ${\bf A}$ is symmetric and PSD. Thanks !.
Edit: I realized that you can rewrite the recurrence relation in slightly cleaner notation as:
$$
\vec{x}_{t + 1} - \vec{x}_{t} =
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}
\exp\left(-\gamma_{i}\left\langle\,\vec{x}_{t}, \vec{e}_{i}\,\right\rangle\right)\,{\bf A}\vec{e}_{i}.
$$
Edit: A possible approach: with the substitution $\vec{z} = \exp(-\vec{\gamma} \odot \vec{x})$, the system reduces to $$
    \frac{d\vec{z}}{dt} = -\vec{\gamma} \odot \mathbf{A} \vec{z} \odot \vec{z},
$$ which is now quadratic in the unknowns. I've still had difficulty finding the general solution of this system, but I can find $\textit{some}$ solutions in $\textit{some}$ situations, for example if $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible then one solution is $$
    \vec{z} = \frac{\mathbf{A}^{-1} (1/\vec{\gamma})}{t},
$$
where $1/\vec{\gamma}$ is a vector whose coordinates are $1/\gamma_i$. I'm not sure about the general case, but again, I only need an approximation.

This turned out to be quite long and complicated, maybe someone can come up with a shorter solution. You have the system of ODEs:
$$\frac{d\vec{x}(t)}{dt} = A \exp(-\gamma \odot \vec{x(t)})
$$
Assuming $\Gamma = \text{diag}[\gamma_1, \ldots \gamma_n]$ and applying the Laplace transform,
$$
sX(s) = A (sI + \Gamma)^{-1}) X(s) + \vec{x}(0) \\
\implies X(s) = \left(sI - A(sI + \Gamma)^{-1} \right)^{-1} \vec{x}(0)
$$
Now, let $(sI + \Gamma)^{-1} = B(s)$. We can write
$$
B(s) = s^{-1}(I +\Gamma  s^{-1})^{-1} \\
= s^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (\Gamma s^{-1})^k
$$
Therefore, we can write
\begin{align*}
(sI - AB(s))^{-1} = s^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty(AB(s) s^{-1})^i \\
= s^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[A \left(s^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k (\Gamma s^{-1})^k\right) s^{-1} \right]^i \\
= s^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[A^i s^{-2i} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{(k+i)} \Gamma^{(k+1)} s^{(-k+i)} \right) \right] \\
= s^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[A^i \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{(k+i)} (\Gamma s^{-1})^{(k+i)} \right) \right]
\end{align*}
Let $k + i = m$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{(k+i)} (\Gamma s^{-1})^{(k+i)} \right) = \left(\sum_{m=i}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} (\Gamma s^{-1})^{m} \right) \\
= \left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} (\Gamma s^{-1})^{m} \right) - \left(\sum_{m=0}^{i} (-1)^{m} (\Gamma s^{-1})^{m} \right) \\
= (I + \Gamma s^{-1})^{-1} - (I + \Gamma^i s^{-i}) (I + \Gamma s^{-1})^{-1} \\
= -\Gamma^i s^{-i} (I + \Gamma s^{-1})^{-1}
\end{align*}
Again, putting this back to the double summation, we have:
\begin{align*}
- s^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \left[A^i \Gamma^i s^{-i} \right] (I + \Gamma s^{-1})^{-1} \\
X(s) = -s^{-1} (I - A\Gamma s^{-1})^{-1} (I + \Gamma s^{-1})^{-1} \\
\boxed{X(s) = -s(sI - A \Gamma)^{-1} (sI + \Gamma)^{-1}}
\end{align*}
Our job is not done yet since this multiplicative form does not correspond to a standard Laplace transform inverse. We still have to take the partial fraction expansion of this to reduce it to additive form. For that, we first expand the PSD matrix as $A \Gamma = Q \Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ is the unitary eigenvector matrix, such that, $QQ^T =I$, and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. We have,
$$
\boxed{A\Gamma = Q \Lambda Q^T}
$$
Now, using this, our Laplace transform becomes:
$$
X(s) = -s(sI - Q\Lambda Q^T)^{-1} (sI + \Gamma)^{-1} \\
= -s Q(sI - \Lambda )^{-1} Q^T (sI + \Gamma)^{-1} \\
$$
Expanding the eigenvector matrix as,
$$ 
Q = \begin{bmatrix} q_{11} & \cdots & q_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{n1} & \cdots & q_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
On multiplying the matrices, we get the following conditions for X(s)
$$
X_{ij}(s) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{-s}{(s+\gamma_i)}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{q^2_{ik}}{(s-\lambda_k)} 
 \ \text{for} \ i = j, \\
\frac{-s}{(s+\gamma_j)} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{q_{ik} q_{jk}}{(s-\lambda_k)} \ \text{for} \ i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
Using partial fraction expansion, we can write:
$$
X_{ij}(s) =  \begin{cases} 
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{q^2_{ik}}{1 + \frac{\gamma_i}{\lambda_k}} \left(-\frac{1}{(s-\lambda_k)} - \frac{\frac{\gamma_i}{\lambda_k}}{(s + \gamma_i)} \right) 
 \ \text{for} \ i = j, \\
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{q_{ik}q_{jk}}{1 + \frac{\gamma_j}{\lambda_k}} \left(-\frac{1}{(s-\lambda_k)} - \frac{\frac{\gamma_j}{\lambda_k}}{(s + \gamma_j)} \right)  \ \text{for} \ i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$
Using the fact that $\mathcal{L}(e^{at}) = \frac{1}{s-a}$, we can write $\vec{x}(t)$ as
$$
\boxed{\mathcal{L}^{-1} (X_{ij}(s)) = 
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{q_{ik}q_{jk}}{1 + \frac{\gamma_j}{\lambda_k}} \left(-e^{\lambda_k t} - \frac{\gamma_j}{\lambda_k}e^{-\gamma_j t} \right)} 
$$

Thanks so much for the response. I'm going to parse through this and see how the solution works in the context within which the problem arose.

Also, I was wondering if you would consider an alternative formulation. If you substitute $\vec{z} = \exp(-\gamma \odot \vec{x})$, the ODE reduces to $\frac{d \vec{z}}{dt} = -B \vec{z} \odot \vec{z},$ where $B$ is PSD and diagonalizable. Is this ODE nicer to handle? Still nonlinear but at least it's polynomial in the coordinates of $\vec{z}$.

First question about your answer: In the first step, how do you compute the Laplace transform of $\exp(-\gamma \odot \vec{x})$? It seems that your derivation states $$
L(\exp(-\gamma \odot \vec{x}))(s) = (sI + \Gamma)^{-1} L(\vec{x})(s).
$$ I don't see how this step works. How do you relate the Laplace transform of $\exp(f(t))$ to the Laplace transform of $f(t)$?

Hmm, I don't think the chain rule applies to the Laplace transform, so this step is wrong. Sorry!
